# LaunchScreen.Storyboard Build Error in New Solutions

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac, xcode12

I was working on a Xamarin.Forms Multiplatform app starting with the Blank Forms App template on Visual Studio for Mac 2019. The project built and ran in the simulator no problem.

I tried to make changes to LaunchScreen.storyboard. The storyboard would not open with right-click -> Xcode Interface Builder, saying I needed XCode 8 or higher (12.3 is installed). The storyboard did open with right-click -> Xcode and I was able to change the image and save the changes to the storyboard.

After the change to the storyboard, the project would no longer build. Any new iOS solutions (Multiplatform Xamarin.Forms or Native, and iOS) would not build, all giving the same error. Any info on resolving this would be appreciated. Constraint: I cannot re-install Visual Studio for Mac since it is in Macincloud.

EDIT: For anyone else who runs into this... At some point I had changed Preferences -> SDK Locations -> Apple -> Apple SDK from the default Xcode (which found Xcode 12.3 at the default location) to Xcode 12.3. I switched it back and the errors stopped. All of the built-in templates work again.

```
objc[18804]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1facbf940) and ?? (0x113e24308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2021-01-05 17:27:03.256 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/SpriteKit.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.257 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/SceneKit.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.260 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/MLKit.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.260 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/Metal.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.260 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/Metal.internal.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.260 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/Intents.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.260 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/IBCompilerPlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.260 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.260 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/Core Data.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.261 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 3928AC50-EA32-404F-9CAF-49710A35483C for plug-in at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/Clang LLVM 1.0.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2021-01-05 17:27:03.275 xcodebuild[18804:670156] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-17707/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/SpecificationTypes/BuiltInSpecifications/Compilers/XCCompilerSpecificationInterfaceBuilder.m:112
Details:  Cannot register <DVTExtension 0x1597ed330: Xcode.IBCocoaTouchBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition.MacCatalyst (Xcode.IBCocoaTouchBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition.MacCatalyst) from com.apple.dt.IDE.IBCocoaBuildSupport> (from /Applications/Xcode12.3.app/Contents/PlugIns/IBCocoaBuildSupport.ideplugin) as a platform definition for maccatalyst, <DVTExtension 0x1597cdf80: Xcode.IBCocoaTouchBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition.MacCatalyst (Xcode.IBCocoaTouchBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition.MacCatalyst) from com.apple.dt.IDE.IBCocoaBuildSupport> (from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IBCocoaBuildSupport.ideplugin) is already registered for that platform name
Object:   <XCCompilerSpecificationInterfaceBuilder>
Method:   +_platformDefinitionsByPlatformName
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x1596246b0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   __77+[XCCompilerSpecificationInterfaceBuilder _platformDefinitionsByPlatformName]_block_invoke_2 (in DevToolsCore)
  4   __77+[XCCompilerSpecificationInterfaceBuilder _platformDefinitionsByPlatformName]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
  5   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_once_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   +[XCCompilerSpecificationInterfaceBuilder _platformDefinitionsByPlatformName] (in DevToolsCore)
  8   __65+[XCCompilerSpecificationInterfaceBuilder allPlatformDefinitions]_block_invoke_2 (in DevToolsCore)
  9   __65+[XCCompilerSpecificationInterfaceBuilder allPlatformDefinitions]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
 10   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11   _dispatch_once_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12   +[XCCompilerSpecificationInterfaceBuilder allPlatformDefinitions] (in DevToolsCore)
 13   __53+[IDEEmbeddedXCSpecProvider targetedDeviceFamilySpec]_block_invoke (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 14   -[NSArray(DVTFoundationClassAdditions) dvt_arrayByApplyingBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 15   +[IDEEmbeddedXCSpecProvider targetedDeviceFamilySpec] (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 16   +[IDEEmbeddedXCSpecProvider XCSpecProvider_specifications] (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
 17   +[XCSpecification registerSpecificationsFromDVTPlugInsForDomains:skippingDomains:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18   XCInitializeCoreIfNeeded (in DevToolsCore)
 19   +[Xcode3CoreInitializer ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in Xcode3Core)
 20   _IDEInitializeBuildSystem (in IDEFoundation)
 21   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
 22   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
 23   main (in xcodebuild)
 24   start (in libdyld.dylib)
sh: line 1: 18806 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode12.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode12.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find ibtool 2> /dev/null
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode12.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode12.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find ibtool 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 34304: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "ibtool", not a developer tool or in PATH (bbb)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error: ibtool exited with code 72
         (bbb)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error: Failed to load ibtool log file `obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone 8-14.3/ibtool-manifests/LaunchScreen.storyboardc`: Failed to parse PList data type: 
         (bbb)
```

Comment: Hi, if you open `LaunchScreen.storyboard` with **iOS Designer** and select **Keep Visual Studio**, whether it works?

Comment: Unfortunately, LaunchScreen.storyboard won't open with iOS Designer. Visual Studio keeps saying I need Xcode 8, even though 12.3 is installed.

Comment: What is the version of vs for Mac, whether it's the latest version?